# creating a 3D scatter plot from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I wanted to  create a 3d scatter from a csv file and I wasn't  able to  print the 3d scatter. My code was like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.loadtxt('3d_sample.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True)

ax1.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

For example,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

x= np.array([1,2,3,4])
y=np.array([5,6,7,8])
z=np.array([9,10,11,12])

ax1.scatter(x,y,z)
plt.show()
```

gives

[image]